# How to remove duplicated rows in a csv file without pandas in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Pandas is not allowed in the solution, only the python standard library is allowed.** I have a csv file that contains one column (left side). How do I remove the duplicated rows to make the csv look exactly like the right side? "25,60" and "60,25" should be seen as a pair of duplicated rows. For each pair of duplicated row, the kept row in format "A,B" where A < B, the removed row should be the one A>B. In this case, "25,60" and "80,123" should be kept. For unique row, it should stay whatever it is.
[image]

Comment: SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Can you please post any code you have tried already and are getting an error from?

Comment: @Any Moose, I have some limited experience play around dataframe using pandas but have no clue how to deal this csv with the python standard library only. My real data is couple thousand rows but I made the sample in my question should be able to summarize what I need to do. Greatly appreciate if you would provide python code!

Comment: Sorry, i only know how to fix broken code... I am unable to write original content...

Comment: You haven't considered all the possibilities. Examples: What if there were two "60,25" lines in the input file, neither of which have  A < B? What if the two numbers were equal? In order to program this you will need to figure-out what should happen in _every_ possible case.

Answer (score 1):

```
k = []
with open('file.csv','r') as dat, open('newfile.csv','w') as f:
    for i in dat:
      a = sorted(int(j) for j in i.split(','))
      if a not in k:
          k.append(a)
          f.write(','.join([str(m) for m in a]) +'\n')
```